# Is there any highlighting or annotating software for ODT -format: LibreOffice or OpenOffice?

Tags: openoffice

I read my LibreOffice/OpenOffice documents with tablets and smartphones.
Is there any software for the ODT -format which allows me to edit such files. 
I often find things which I should fix and would like to note that to the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no such software. However, the LibreOffice team is working on an app. A prototype was reviewed e.g. [here](http://liliputing.com/2012/07/libreoffice-coming-to-android-heres-what-it-looks-like-so-far.html), if you want to take a look. No release date so far, but it will hopefully hit the market soon -- it is really strongly needed, as there is not a single Office app capable of working with OpenDocument formats (aside from AndrOffice, which is a spreadsheet-only app and obviously discontinued, as it is no longer listed on the playstore).

Until then: There's a Viewer app available at least, [OpenOffice Document Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.tomtasche.reader)...

---

**UPDATE:** Meanwhile, things have changed, and you have the choice between [AndrOpen Office](http://www.appbrain.com/app/AndrOpen-Office/com.andropenoffice) and [TextMaker Mobile](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Office-2012-TextMaker-Mobile/softmaker.applications.textmaker) for read/write access, as well as [Coffice](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Coffice/org.kde.calligra.coffice) and the already mentioned [OpenDocument Reader](http://www.appbrain.com/app/OpenDocument-Reader/at.tomtasche.reader) for read-only access.

Answer (score 1):

[TextMaker Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=softmaker.applications.textmaker) is the only word processor that lets you open / save `.odt` - plus plenty of other formats, and you may convert one into another.

This app is full of features, e.g., including a very good on-the-fly spell checker, footnotes, endnotes, comments, track changes, embedding of any font, access to several file hosting services etc., all TrueType and openType fonts can be embedded, it has a broad range of formatting and layout options, access and so much more.

Comment: Not the only one, see [AndrOpen Office](http://www.appbrain.com/app/AndrOpen-Office/com.andropenoffice). But you're correct, my answer is no longer up-to-date :)