# Is there any way to edit ODT documents on Android?

Tags: text-editor

I need to edit my OpenOffice documents.

Is there any version of LibreOffice for Android?

Or

Is there any ODT texteditor app for Android?

Comment: You may wish to check [Is there any highlighting or annotating software for ODT -format: LibreOffice or OpenOffice?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19266/is-there-any-highlighting-or-annotating-software-for-odt-format-libreoffice-or/27167#27167) for reference. Short answer: No, currently there's not -- but yes, something is coming (hopefully soon).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is [AndrOpen Office](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andropenoffice)

> AndrOpen Office is the world's first port of OpenOffice for Android.
>
> You can view, edit, export office documents using full features of the OpenOffice.
>
> AndrOpen Office has 6 components:
>
> - Writer (a word processor)
> - Calc (spreadsheet)
> - Impress (presentation graphics)
> - Draw (drawing)
> - Math (equation editor)
> - Base (database)
>
> * AndrOpen Office is forked project from the Apache OpenOffice project.
>
> AndrOpen Office is not affiliated with the Apache OpenOffice project.

Comment: I didn't vote down but consider this solution as a very both inconvenient and user unfriendly one.

Comment: It is, initially, a very poor UX, as it's a desktop application with a desktop interface on a mobile device. As OO is heavily customizable, however, you can make it into something that isn't much different than most mobile office applications. These are a few things I've done to make it a better experience on a phone: Choose big icons, and only the ones you frequently use, switch to "web" instead of page display.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, not really an ODT editor, but Google Docs accepts ODT and you can edit Google Docs on Android. The file would have to be converted to Google Docs internal format then exported back to ODT though.

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is not a single solution on Android for *editing* ODF files. But keep your heads up: The LibreOffice team is [working hard on an Android version](http://liliputing.com/2012/07/libreoffice-coming-to-android-heres-what-it-looks-like-so-far.html) of the entire office suite!

[image: LibreOffice Android version]

Though this is already "old news", and has been heard about for at least half a year, the screenshots look very promising -- at least with a tablet in mind.

Which leaves us with the question: [When Libre Office will be available for Android Smartphones?](http://ask.libreoffice.org/question/538/is-libreoffice-available-for-android/) If you read the information on the linked page (which hopefully will be updated with more details when available), it very much looks like the standard Debian answer: *It's ready when it's ready.*

Answer (score 1):

[Zoho Writer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zoho.writer) seems to support viewing & editing ODT files (only tested with a very simple document):

> ...
>
> - Supports saving of documents in different formats like doc,docx,rtf,odt,txt,html and PDF

Though it seems to work awkwardly:

- Can't directly open a file from disk, first step is importing the file.
- Can't directly save file, must find a hidden "Export" button first.
- Google Play reviewers have many strange bugs to report. After trying it for a few seconds I have noticed some strange redrawing issues.

Answer (score 1):

According to [LibreOffice's website](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/android-and-ios/), Collabora Office is considered the defacto product for iOS and Android:

> While The Document Foundation doesn’t currently offer an Android or iOS version of LibreOffice, there is a LibreOffice-based product in app stores from Collabora, one of our certified developers and ecosystem members

Find out more on the [Collabora Office for Android & iOS](https://www.collaboraoffice.com/collabora-office-android-ios/) page. A few highlights:

- [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.collabora.libreoffice), [App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/collabora-office/id1440482071), and [F-Droid listings](https://www.collaboraoffice.com/releases-en/collabora-office-on-mobiles-supporting-password-protected-documents-and-available-on-f-droid/)
- Based on [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software) principles
- Private by default
- Interoperable with Microsoft Office and Open Document standards

Answer (score 0):

[OpenDocument Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.tomtasche.reader) is worth checking out. It will be really good but the save function doesn't work yet. They are still working on it so when that gets updated it will be far better than AndrOpen as the interface isn't cluttered so you can actually type on it easily! You will be able to then save to dropbox, Google Drive, your email or where ever...

update: not sure the programmers are ever going to fix it. They seem a bit odd.

Comment: An editing app that doesn't save isn't really useful, is it?

Comment: On their site they said they were about to update it. If they had done, it would have been the most useful of the bunch.

Answer (score 0):

[Collabora Office](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.collabora.libreoffice), a LibreOffice derivative, works well on my tablet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

A quick note, the default app on an Android phone such as "QuickOffice" should work. Try opening the doc as 'open As' and then select QuickOffice if available on your device.

Comment: Have you tried this, ODT isn't just a text file, and isn't just an Office .doc? [QuickOffice Pro](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.qo.android.am3)'s Market listing only mentions that it can open and edit these files, none of which are [Open Document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) compatible: .doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, .ppt .pptx & .pdf

Comment: Good point, I haven't tried it personally.